# Android show SMS in inbox from some other resource

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-manifest

Well!! My question is little weird .. I have created an chat channel which send text using one XMPP server.. Now I want to show the incoming chat as a sms in inbox.. Is there a way I can send sms/show sms in message inbox of android phone?

what I want to achieve is that if a person A sends an SMS to person B (then I will intercept the out going SMS and send it via chat)

Waiting for the comments!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/) to manage the SMS functionality.

Comment: I want to do it programatically